# GET request in FTP

Tags: java, sockets, ftp

i need help in sending request to FTP server for downloading a file...
i have written the following code to download a file using HTTP it work successfully but i don't know how to do for a FTP.....
as i have used socket for making connection it has to be done through this way just suggest me what will be the format of a request (to send to server) for download a FTP file......

///////////////////////////coding////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 URL url_of_file=new URL("http://fs36.filehippo.com/4281/856e12e1656d480da79ef2b40581f75e/npp.6.2.Installer.exe");
       String hostaddress=url_of_file.getHost();

       Socket mysocket3 = new java.net.Socket();

    //create socket to server for HTTP use port 80 for FTP use 21 //

       mysocket3.connect(new InetSocketAddress(hostaddress,80));


        OutputStream os = mysocket3.getOutputStream();
         int file_size=5860557;

       //REQUEST Formate for HTTP ..........//

         String getRequest = "GET " + url_of_file + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +            
            "Host: "+ hostaddress + "\r\n" + 
            "Range: bytes=0-"+file_size+" \r\n\r\n";  

         os.write(getRequest.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        os.flush();
        InputStream in = mysocket3.getInputStream();



        // 2. Recieving the  data,..............
```

Answer (score 5):

FTP is a **different protocol** from HTTP. There is no "GET" request in FTP. In order to understand how the requests and responses look, read the [**RFC959**](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) FTP specification.

From a Java perspective, you could try **[org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html)

```
FTPClient f = new FTPClient();
f.connect(server);
f.login(username, password);
```

Comment: is there any way to download the particular portion of a file in FTP... for example if file total size is 5000kb then is there any way to download file from Range 2000kb --to--3000kb.//thanks

Comment: @user1547163  I think no you will need to download entire file.